# Error code 2 when calling Siemens WinAC ODK Open()

Tags: .net, interop, siemens

After a Windows/system update, my app (.NET 4.7.1 running on Win 7) for actuator control is no longer working.
I am using Siemens WinAC ODK 4.2 in SMX mode to control a PLC connected to Festo actuators.

I now get error code 2 when calling S7SMX_Open() (via interop) in S7smxx.dll.
That error code is defined as "S7SMX_ERR_NO_LOCATOR" in my program.

Method declaration:

```
// Open SMX connection
        [DllImport(@"S7smxx.dll", EntryPoint = "?S7SMX_Open@@YAHKPBDPAPAX@Z", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern errorCodes S7SMX_Open(flags dwFlags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pDeviceName, out IntPtr phHandle);
```

The main thread in the program is marked as using a single threaded apartment (STAThread).

I have looked at the Siemens forums without much luck.

What does the error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is fixed now.

It was caused by several Windows Update patches related to Meltdown/Spectre. These patches are incompatible with RTX 2009, causing it to stop working.

After uninstalling the patches, the system is working again.

https://confluence.merging.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=25035234